# Vuetify : How to set selected item background color in v-select

Tags: css, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, v-select

I have this v-select and I want to change the background color of the selected item to 'white' and keep the text color in blue

[image]

I have tried to add **item-color** attribute to my v-select but it changes the background and the text color so we can't see the text anymore.
I also tried to add a scoped style like this but it doesn't work :(

```
.v-list-item--active {
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

Any one can help ?

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by using the `item` prop of the v-select and placing a v-list-item inside.

```html
<v-select
  :items="[1,2,3]"
  multiple
>
  <template v-slot:item="{item, on, attrs}">
    <v-list-item v-on="on">
      <v-list-item-action>
        <v-simple-checkbox
          :value="attrs.inputValue"
          v-on="on"
          color="primary"
          :ripple="false"
        ></v-simple-checkbox>
      </v-list-item-action>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title :class="attrs.inputValue ? 'primary--text' : ''">
          {{ item }}
        </v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
  </template>
</v-select>
```

`attrs.inputValue` holds the selected state of the item which I use to set the `primary--text` class on the v-list-item-title.

FYI: The `:ripple="false"` attribute on the v-simple-checkbox is necessary to prevent errors in the console, because there is an open [bug](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/12224) with the ripple directive on this component.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know if its the effect that you're looking for but to preserve the dark mode you should instead remove the opacity from the active element

```
.v-list-item--active::before { opacity: 0 }
```

Keep in mind that this rule applies to all list items active.

If you want to do it on a single select or only on selects, you should target the elements that you want

```
/* Examples */

.v-select .v-list-item--active::before { opacity: 0 }
.v-select--is-multi .v-list-item--active::before { opacity: 0 }
.my-pale-select  .v-list-item--active::before { opacity: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
.v-list .v-list-item--link:before{
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/MNSY22/pen/MWjdmGg) is codepen simple.

Answer (score 0):

For me, styling the item inside the v-select works only if I remove `scoped` from the style block:

```css
<style>
  .v-list-item--active {
     background-color: white;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).